# admob to deprecate sdk to replace with Ads SDK 7.0.0 - how to upgrade just admob jar in google play services

Tags: android, admob

Let me show you my current build dependencies so you understand my frustation:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.+'
    //for now disable wearApp  dependency for PaidRelease builds
    wearApp project(':wearable')
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
}
```

and here are my wearable dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
}
```

Notice in my apps dependencies i am using 8.3.+ for the version meaning only update minor version changes.  Admob wrote me the following a few days ago:

In order to ensure that your ads continue to serve after September 15th, 2016, please upgrade to Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.0.0 or higher.

They said one way to do this is to just update the entire google play services to 9.0.2.  But I am not using entire Play Service dependencies. As you can see I just get the exact packages I need to save space and method count.

**The issue:**

If I were to replace the following line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
```

I am not confident it will work with the 8.3.+ jars I depend on. Wont I have to update the entire google play services jars I am using to be 9.0.+ also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using version 8.3 as denoted by `play-services-ads:8.3.+`, well above the 7.0.0 cutoff, so there's no action needed on your part.

Comment: However yes, if you want to upgrade to a 9.X version, you'd need to upgrade all of your dependencies.